# Converting a sql query to rails activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple problem . I am not able to figure out the rails equivalent for this sql query:

`select COUNT(description) from reports where user_id = current_user;`

Actually I want to count the total no. of reports posted by a particular user when logged in his account and not the all reports posted by all users.
I am also not able to figure out that how should I pass the user_id of the current user logged in so that I can get the required result. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
current_user.reports.count
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 2

If you have defined `has_many :reports` in User model.

```
count = current_user.reports.first(:select => "COUNT(description) as count").count
```

If `has_many` is not defined in the model,

```
count = Report.first(:select => "COUNT(description) as count",
             :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id}).count
```

But `current_user.reports.select{ |report| report.description }.count` is enough though it produces a different query. (`Select * from reports where ..`) and then take the count of the array.

But in Rails 3, it is quite easy.

If you have defined `has_many :reports` in User model.

```
count = current_user.reports.count(:description)
```

otherwise

```
count = Report.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count(:description)
```

Refer [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations) for Rails 3 AR calculation queries.